# Transit with United via the U.S. to Mexico

Tags: usa, transit, connecting-flights, united-airlines

I'm flying via the U.S. for the first time from Europe (Munich, Germany) with United and I wanted to know if I need to get my bags at the transit airport (IAH, Houston) and check them again for my connecting flight to Cancun, Mexico or if they will be forwarded?

Also I wanted to know if I need to go through immigration at the transit airport?

Thanks in advance for your help
Simon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to go through the US customs and immigration, and that includes taking your bags. You'll re-check them in with United right after the customs (look for "connections" sign).

They'll probably be tagged all the way to Cancun when you first check them in in Munich, so make sure to leave the tags intact attached to the luggage when you pick them up to go through the US customs.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the fast and thorough answer. Do you think 1 hour and 45min is enough time to do all that?

Comment: @s137 if they sold you the ticket then United think it is. It depends on how long the immigration line would be and whether your flight is delayed in MUC/late into IAH. If you miss the connection, United should take care of you.

Comment: Alright, thanks. That's basicallly what I thought too. Thanks for confirming it though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is this a single ticket with one PNR that you bought from United? Or two tickets on United that you bought in separate transactions?

Comment: Its one Ticket with one PNR.

Comment: Interestingly enough two United Crew Members just told me that that's not true and Houston is an exception to that rule. They both indepentently from one another said, my baggage will be routed through directly to Cancun without me needing to get it and recheck it after customs.

Comment: @s137 I know that when transiting through some airports in Canada they do that, I wasn't aware that they started doing it in any US airports. If so then it is in fact, unfortunately, an exception to the rule.

Comment: I'm actually still not 100% convinced they are right, because literally everyone will tell you, that you have to recheck your bags at the first U.S. airport you come to, but I do really hope they are right on this. We'll see if I end up without my bag in Cancun^^